# Php login error password or username wrong

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i'm facing a serious problem when i try to connect to an account!! always showing error password or username wrong! i'm using md5 hashed password in mysql !! here's my login page code and mysql table query image :

```
    <?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once('module/config.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    header("location: index.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $identification = $_POST['username'];
    $identification = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $identification);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);

    if($identification == "" || $password == "")
        {
            echo "Error Username / Password Wrong !";
        }else {

            $sql ="SELECT * FROM usrr WHERE usrname='$identification' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            if (!$query ) { die(mysqli_error($link)); } 
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $id= $row['uid'];
            $db_pss =$row['usrpass'];
            if (password_verify($password, $db_pss)){
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
                header("location: index.php");

            }else{
                echo "Error Username / Password Wrong !";
            }

        }
}


?>


<form method="post">
<label>username : </label>
<input type="text" name="username"><br/>
<label>password : </label>
<input type="password" name="password"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="login">

</form>
```

[MYSQL TABLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLXg6.png)

Comment: Please dont use `md5 ` for password.

Comment: Please use [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as you can still bypass `mysqli_real_escape_string` under some circumstances. Also note that you are not escaping your `$_POST['username']`

Comment: As Eddie said, never ever use md5 for password hashing. Use PHPs `password_hash()` with `password_verify()`

Comment: can you please help me by beign more specific what to do ! i don't understand this kind of strong language i'm not a coder i just have little knewledge and i'm just using pre-made website ! thanks you very much

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt how can i do that ?

Comment: @AhmedHamada is the question solved (or not) ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- no still not yet :( i'm struggling big time :/

Comment: @AhmedHamada and amidst the (new) comment / suggestion under the answer still didn't solve it?

Answer (score 2):

`password_verify` works on `password_hash` and NOT on `md5` hash

Please check the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

UPDATE:

The problem is actually on the **sign up or adding the user on the DB**. **Not** on the sign in.

When the user sign up use this

```
$pwHash = password_hash($userPasssword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

`$pwHash` is the hash that you should save on the DB. **Not** the `md5`

Then you can use your sign in code above. No need to change it.

Comment: Oh didnt see you answered exactly this, take my upvote as compensation :)

Comment: iam sorry for beign a dumb cuz i'm not good at coding and things i just know some little basics and i'm using pre made website ! so is there anything wrong with the code above and there's something i need to change or what

Comment: Short: You cant use password_verify() without password_hash(), as you posted you used md5 for the hashing.

Comment: @AhmedHamada so instead on `$pwHash = md5 ('password')` you do `$pwHash = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` and save it on the DB. This is on sign up.

Comment: @AhmedHamada Then you can use your code above to verify ( sign in )

Comment: @Eddie is there a way i can give you my webhost login so you can do it for me if you can please !  .?

Comment: @AhmedHamada I wouldn't do that. For too many reasons. I'm not saying Eddie can't be trusted, but there may be others on here who may not be trusted and even some non-members of the Stack network.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i understand yeah but i'm really getting mad day by day without solving this problem ! i know it just need 10 min of any experienced user who can fix it which can be better than posting every day for help on every website !(

Comment: I agree with @Fred-ii- It is not advisable to give your host credentials. I also dont want to be responsible for it

Comment: I updated the code. If you are still having a problem, please post you sign up code ( The code where you save the password to DB )

Comment: on what line should i add this ? $pwHash = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT) !!! and by the way here's my sign up code <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="Enter your Password"/>

Comment: Post the php code where you save the data on the db for signUp